# What is the translation termination efficiency in mammalian cells?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, translation, protein-expression

When I express proteins in bacteria I put at least two stop codons at the end of the gene to increase the termination efficiency. Is this the case in eukaryotic cells too? If I put a single stop codon is there a risk for the ribosomal complex to readthrough and continue translation?

Comment: There is no such practice as far as I know. Personally I have never done that and things work fine. You can add a polyadenylation signal, though. 

Is this a synthetic gene or something ?

Comment: From what I understand the eRFs are not perfect but they still work better than RF1 and RF2 which allow for a non trivial amount of readthrough.

Comment: This is a synthetic gene. I already designed a primer with 3 stop codons at the end of the gene. I will post here again if I see any improvement in gene expression (with compared to other similar constructs in our lab).

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper for transfection of mammalian cells here which has a bit of [comparison of stop codon and protein yield](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1472-6750-13-52).

Otherwise [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkl074) suggests having a 'rare' codon after the stop to prevent readthrough. But yes, I'm not sure why one wouldn't simply put two stops after each other.